# Does ng build avoid node_modules code duplication?

Tags: angular, npm

We a have a large angular application and each module that the app uses is in a seperate repo and is build to be imported in the main application for example.

I have a npm library lets call it `lib1`. Now my two modules `module1` and `module2` use that library.
I make a build using `ng build` of `module1` and `module2`. Then I add these modules in my main app in the `app.module.ts` file and use them in the app. Now If I build my main app will it include the minified code of `lib1` twice or the compiler will recognize and package the `lib1` only once to be used by the app. My main concern is the package size. Is it going to increase? Would it be better if I don't keep the modules in separately and directly include their code in the main rather than their builds and build the main app once.

Comment: I cannot assure you, but I believe that in the case that you have explained, the compiler will recognize and package the lib1 only once, I say this assuming that it behaves similarly to lazy loading of modules, that can remember what has already been added modules The easiest would be to create a new project and try it.

Comment: but the build code is minifed + uglified to an extent that I might be able to look it into it once it's built. so looking for a certainty here as our application is going to grow overtime and we don't want it to bulk in size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after testing myself I've seen that it avoids the duplication, so for example if you are using lodash in multiple modules and then you include those modules into the main app then the lodash could should only be included once as long as the version of lodash is the same, otherwise not. Hence it's important to keep your versions same for all the modules

Answer (score 1):

I've tested that it avoids the duplication, so for example if you are using lodash in multiple modules and then you include those modules into the main app then the lodash could should only be included once as long as the version of lodash is the same, otherwise not. Hence it's important to keep your versions same for all the modules